# Training custom dataset on mmsegmentation

Tags: python, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to do semantic segmentation on Freiburg Forest dataset using mmsegmentation repo on github. The link to the same is attached below.

https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmsegmentation

I have made config file for the Freiburg Forest dataset and I have also added dataset file to `/mmsetg/datatsets` folder. When I am trying to training with single GPU,I am getting following error.

I am not able to understand, where else should I add this custom dataset so that model will accept it.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 122, in build_from_cfg
    obj = obj_cls(**args)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 219, in __init__
    super().__init__(runner, dataloader)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/base_loop.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.dataloader = runner.build_dataloader(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1346, in build_dataloader
    dataset = DATASETS.build(dataset_cfg)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/registry/registry.py", line 548, in build
    return self.build_func(cfg, *args, **kwargs, registry=self)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 100, in build_from_cfg
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: 'FreiburgForestDataset is not in the dataset registry. Please check whether the value of `FreiburgForestDataset` is correct or it was registered as expected. More details can be found at https://mmengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_tutorials/config.html#import-the-custom-module'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also need to import it in [this](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmsegmentation/blob/main/mmseg/datasets/__init__.py) file and add it to `__all__`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that and let you know what happened.